# How to show in the same Form Grid, Header and Line records?

Tags: forms, gridview, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++

I have a problem. I need to have in the same *Form's Grid* both Header record and Line record.

My Header is **CustInvoiceJour** my Line is **CustInvoiceTrans** the Table relation is by : *CustInvoiceTrans.ParentRecId == CustInvoiceJour.RecId*.

I want to show some CustInvoiceJour fields and another CustInvoiceTrans fields in the same grid.

On web I found this [tutorial](https://community.dynamics.com/ax/b/goshoom/archive/2013/11/27/lines-for-multiple-headers) : but I forget something or I need more information. 
Because I only see an only one CustInvoiceJour with it Line, and all other Header and its aren't show.

Can you help me ? Do you have another explain example or advice ?

Comment: Do you have one grid or two grids? Can you be more specific on the fields or the expected output.

Comment: can you add what query your datasources generate?

Comment: I have only one Grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `CustInvoiceJour` and `CustInvoiceTrans` as data sources. On the `CustInvoiceTrans` datasource change properties `JoinSource` to `CustInvoiceJour` and `LinkType` to `InnerJoin`.

On the grid control set the `DataSource` property to `CustInvoiceJour`.

Drag the fields from datasources to the field.

Comment: very helpful! Work well!

Answer (score 1):

You could create a new query that has both of those tables in the dataset using the relation you described above.

After you create your query, you can add that query to your form grid as the datasource.

OR

Use the query called CustInvoiceTransExpanded which has both tables you mention plus a few others that might be useful.